# MSIEXEC /x returning "1603" Process Exit Code

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer

I'm trying to uninstall a software using "msiexec /x" command embedded in a process of a simple console application.

But in the device with UAC - Never Notify, uninstallation fails with following process exit code - 1603.

Please help in this regard.

Comment: Did you create the msi?

Comment: also try to obtain more log information by using `msiexec /lvx logifile.log`

Comment: We need more context for this. Why are you launching the uninstall from a console application?

Comment: same issue need inputs